# Newer version of GCC throws invalid conversion error

Tags: c++, type-conversion, offset, gcc-warning

```
    class FixedDataBlock: public DataBlockHeaderCommon<BlockSize>
    {
    // Construction
    public:
        FixedDataBlock(void* pool, SizeT const entrySize, SizeT const alignment)
            : base_t(eBlkFixData, pool)
        {
            this_t* dummy = reinterpret_cast<this_t*>(0);
            // offsets is a type of uint16_t
            OffsetT dataStartBlockOffset = reinterpret_cast<OffsetT>( &dummy->data[0] );

        }

    // Member variables
    private:
        int8_t      data[ BlockSize-sizeof(header_t) ];
    };
```

error: invalid type conversion: "int8_t={signed char} *" to "uint16_t={unsigned short}" for line

OffsetT dataStartBlockOffset = reinterpret_cast( &dummy->data[0] );

//dummy->data[0] is signed char* and dataStartBlockOffset is unsigned short

The above code is compiling fine on windows but it is failing only with the GCC.

Comment: Can you reduce your code the problem please!

Comment: `this_t* dummy = reinterpret_cast<this_t*>(0);
            // offsets is a type of uint16_t
            OffsetT dataStartBlockOffset = reinterpret_cast<OffsetT>( &dummy->data[0] );` - that looks wrong in several ways. First, there are vary few things you can validly do with `reinterpret_cast` and these don't look like any of them. Secondly, that `dummy` dereference is dereferencing a `nullptr` that's definitely [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

Comment: The purpose of code is to get offset for object member data[] from the start of the object, the offset will be constant value but it might change considering different OS environments. The code is dealing with the MMF and offset pointers.

Comment: Compiler errors are not exceptions, and they are printed, not thrown. Don't abuse standard terminology.

Comment: please format your question properly https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Answer (score 0):

Using offsetof micro fixed compilation error.
OffsetT dataStartBlockOffset = (OffsetT)offsetof(FixedDataBlock, data);